# Variable containing the total horizontal length of a table

Tags: tables, minipage, lengths

I am trying to put a **minipage** inmediately below a **table**, the minipage will be scaled X.Y times the total horizontal length of the previous **table**. Since I have several tables with variable cells' contents, I cannot set each horizontal length manually for each minipage.

Is there a way to access this length either from the **table** or **tabular** environments?

I tried with the common variables: `\linewidth`, `\columnwidth`, among others.

I have also searched everywhere with no luck.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I were you, I would use the `tablenotes` environment of package `threeparttable`, which measures the table width.

Comment: Yu can use `\settoheight` with the `tabular` as the second argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply put the tabular in a box and measure the width of the box with `\wd`.

In the following example, I have used a multiplicative factor of 120%.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for dummy text

\begin{document}

\newbox{\MyTabular}
\newlength{\tabularwidth}

\savebox\MyTabular
{\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\toprule
one & two & three \\
some text & other text & some more text \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}}

\setlength{\tabularwidth}{\wd\MyTabular}

\begin{center}
\usebox\MyTabular
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{1.2\tabularwidth}
\lipsum[1]
\end{minipage}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]